# Java proper parsing

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns

I m finding the best way to parse hand written data into objects.

Lets say I have an interface called `IEvent`.

Lets say I have two class `EventNewPlayer` and `EventUpdateTime` which both implements the interface `IEvent`

The class `EventNewPlayer` requires 2 integers and one string. Lets say position `X` and `Y` and the name of the player

The class `EventUpdateTime` only requires one argument: the time.

I would like to make as create as much events as I want, from a hand written file

The file would look like this:

```
NEWPLAYER, 4, 2, joe
NEWPLAYER, 8, 9, bob
UPDATETIME, 1
NEWPLAYER, 8, 9, carl
UPDATETIME, 3
```

I would like to generate a list of events from this file.
Also I would like in the future to add as much event as I want.

What is the best/proper/maintenable way to do this?

Sorry about any english mistakes, English is not my first langage.

Comment: SO is not the homework resolving resource. Come here with your code attempts which have some particular problem

Comment: @IvanPronin I m not asking for code. I don't need to write code to know its not the good way to do it (splitting on "," and conditions would be really easy but dirty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OOP-esque way of doing this:

1) Create a base interface called `StringEventFactory`, and a non-static function called `parseFromArray`, taking a string array as argument and returning an `IEvent`; also create a static function called `className`, which returns the in-file name for each event class.

2) For each event create a corresponding `...Factory` class which inherits from `StringEventFactory`, and implement the `parseFromArray` function to create an event of that type from the string array data.

3) Create a *hash table*, whose:

- Keys are the class names stored in the text file, e.g. "NEWPLAYER" etc.
- Values are the corresponding class `..Factory` objects

4) For each line split it into a string array, and use the first element to fetch the `StringEventFactory` object from the hashtable. Pass the rest of the array to its `parseFromArray` function to create the event object you want

This way it is very easy to add new class specifications, without using an ugly `switch` statement.

---

EDIT: Code + slight change in specification

```
 interface StringEventFactory {
    public static string className();
    public IEvent parseFromArray(string[]);
 };

 class EventNewPlayerFactory implements StringEventFactory
 {
    public static string className() { return "NEWPLAYER"; }

    public IEvent parseFromArray(string[] info) 
    {
        if (info.length != 4) // includes the class name
            return null;

        // sanity check
        if (!info[0].equals(className()) || info[3].isEmpty()) 
            return null;

        int x, y;
        try {
            x = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // notify?
            return null;
        }

        return new EventNewPlayer(x, y, info[3]);
    }
 };

 // similarly for EventUpdateTime ...

 // main body
 public static void main(string[] args)
 {
    Hashtable<string, StringEventFactory> factories = new Hashtable<string, StringEventFactory>();

    factories.put(EventNewPlayerFactory.className(), new EventNewPlayerFactory());
    // similarly for other classes

    List<IEvent> eventList = new ArrayList();

    // file parsing
    FileReader input = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(input);
    String line = null;

    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null)
    {    
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = array[i].trim();

        // fetch the factory class
        StringEventFactory fact = factories.get(array[0]);
        if (fact == null) {
            // class name does not exist
            continue;
        }

        StringEvent out = fact.parseFromArray(array);
        if (out == null) {
            // parameters were incorrect!
            continue;
        }

        // success! add to list
        eventList.add(out);
    }
 }
```

Sorry if it doesn't work straight out of the bag and has syntax errors, my Java is slightly rusty, but the gist is hopefully what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given a data array of

```
String[] data = { "ObjA,0,0,Bob", "ObjB,0" };
```

And an Enum defined as

```
public enum MyEnum {

    ObjA, ObjB;
}
```

I would use something like:

```
for ( String line : data ) {

    Object obj;

    String[] parts = line.split(",");

    switch(MyEnum.valueOf(parts[0])) {

        case ObjA:
            obj = new ObjectOfTypeA(parts);
            break;

        case ObjB:
            obj = new ObjectOfTypeB(parts);
            break;
    }
```

Each object could then handle their own arguments:

```
public ObjectOfTypeA(String[] params) {

    x = params[1];
    y = params[2];
    name = params[3];
}
```

And

```
public ObjectOfTypeB(String[] params) {

    ticks = params[1];
}
```

For every new object you create, you will be required to add it to the Enum list, the switch case, and then obviously the creation of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use Finite State Machine. It is simple and flexible for maintenance. You can add different handlers in future.

Here is my example for XML parsing - https://github.com/kurkov/XMLParser 
But you can make something similar for text file parsing.